# How do I calculate percentage change for consecutive days only?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a Pandas dataframe. I want to calculate the percentage change of the values. My data has some gaps, so I want to calculate the percentage change based on consecutive days only.

Original data:

```
             date    value 
0      2020-08-05   123.45    # (Wednesday)
1      2020-08-06   678.90    # (Thursday)
2      2020-08-07   234.56    # (Friday)
3      2020-08-10   789.01    # (Monday)
4      2020-08-11   345.67    # (Tuesday)
5      2020-08-12   345.67    # (Wednesday)
...
```

Expected result:

```
             date    value   percent_change
0      2020-08-05   123.45              NaN
1      2020-08-06   678.90           449.94
2      2020-08-07   234.56           -65.45
3      2020-08-10   789.01              NaN
4      2020-08-11   345.67           -56.19
5      2020-08-12   345.67                0
...
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where` to check the difference of each consecutive date:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df["percent_change"] = np.where(df["date"].diff().dt.days.eq(1),
                                df["value"].pct_change()*100, 
                                np.NaN)

print (df)

        date   value  percent_change
0 2020-08-05  123.45             NaN
1 2020-08-06  678.90      449.939247
2 2020-08-07  234.56      -65.449993
3 2020-08-10  789.01             NaN
4 2020-08-11  345.67      -56.189402
5 2020-08-12  345.67        0.000000
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic way to solve this in my opinion.

Comment: What if the dates are ordered from the newest to the oldest (e.g. `2020-08-12` first, and `2020-08-05` last)?

Comment: Just sort using `sort_values`.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.pct_change`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df.set_index("date")
df["pct_change"] = df.asfreq("1d").pct_change(fill_method=None)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             value  pct_change
date                          
2010-08-05  123.45         NaN
2010-08-06  678.90    4.499392
2010-08-07  234.56   -0.654500
2010-08-10  789.01         NaN
2010-08-11  345.67   -0.561894
2010-08-12  345.67    0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relativedelta` and `shift()`. Create a mask `m` that returns `True` or `False` if a date is one day after the row before it. Then, use `np.where()` to do the calculation for those rows, where you compare one row to the row before it with `.shift()`. Another answer suggests using `pct_chg()`, which you can also use.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
# df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
m = (df.shift()['date'] == df['date'].dt.date - relativedelta(days=1))
df['percent_change'] = np.where(m, (df['value']/df.shift()['value']-1)*100, np.nan)
df

Out[34]: 
        date   value  percent_change
0 2010-08-05  123.45             NaN
1 2010-08-06  678.90      449.939247
2 2010-08-07  234.56      -65.449993
3 2010-08-10  789.01             NaN
4 2010-08-11  345.67      -56.189402
5 2010-08-12  345.67        0.000000
```